# To remove an item in List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, list

I am trying to remove an item in my `gcNumber` but it is not getting removed. Below is my code. i know i am doing some silly thing but don't know where :(

```
 var gcn=gcNumber.ToList();
 foreach (var selectGc in gcn)
   {                
        var countToRemove = _uow.GetRepository<TripSheetGcDetail>().GetAll().Where(x => x.FkGcId == selectGc.Id && x.IsActive == true).Select(y => y);
        if(countToRemove .Count()>0)
        {                   
            gcNumber.ToList().Remove(selectGc);
        }
        else
        {
        }

   }
    return gcNumber.ToList();
```

if my `CountToRemove.count()>0` then i want to remove that item in my `gcNumber` list. Kindly help where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gcNumber.ToList().Remove(selectGc);
```

This line creates a new list, which you remove stuff from, then since you don't do anything else (like assign the list any where) throws the modified list away.

I'm guessing what you want to do instead is something like:

```
gcn.Remove(selectGc);
```

You also want to modify your `foreach` so that it isn't looping over something that is getting modified.

```
foreach(var selectGg in gcNumber)
```

This will loop over the original thing, allowing you to modify the copy.

And you'll probably want to return `gcn`, as your return statement just creates another new list based on `gcNumber` which hasn't been modified.

In summary: `.ToList()` creates a new list every time, so modifying that list won't do anything to the original.

Comment: i applied `gcn.Remove(selectGc);` but when it go to foreach it throw an error `gcn` is modified

Comment: You can't modify the thing you are iterating over. your foreach should probably look like this:
`foreach (var selectGc in gcn.ToList())` So that you loop over a copy, not the version being modified.

Comment: Or `foreach(var selectGg in gcNumber)` which is the original, before you copied it to a new list.

Comment: got that. Thank you for your valuable comment.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `gcNumber.ToList().Remove(selectGc);` just do `gcNumber.Remove(selectGc);`

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string Name {get; set;}  
    }

    public static void Main()
    {

        var list = new List<MyClass>();

        list.Add(new MyClass() {Name = "aaa"});
        list.Add(new MyClass() {Name = "bbb"});
        list.Add(new MyClass() {Name = "ccc"});
        list.Add(new MyClass() {Name = "ddd"});

        var indexesToRemove = new List<int>();

        foreach(var item in list)
        {
                if(item.Name == "aaa")
                    indexesToRemove.Add(list.IndexOf(item));
        }

        foreach (var num in indexesToRemove)
            list.RemoveAt(num);


            Console.WriteLine(list.First().Name);

    }
}
```

Maby it is not the best way to remove items from list but it's clear. You can't remove items form list which is enumerating.